# In R, help converting a regular table into a ggplot table with borders?

Tags: r

Here is my current table code:

```
reftable <- matrix(c("181198", "234321", "306789", "16000234"), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(reftable) <- c("Score")
rownames(reftable) <- c("How I Met Your Mother", "There Are No Ifs, Ands, Or Buts in the Land of Fantasies and Dreams", "Leo and Carrie Simply Cannot Get Along", "Parry Needs A Dentist")
reftable <- as.table(reftable)
reftable
```

However, when I knit this code to a pdf, all the numbers turn into hashtags and it's hard to read because there are no border lines. How do I convert this into a ggplot table so that there are border lines on the tables and the inputted numbers are preserved?

Answer (score 2):

library `gridExtra` may help you

```
library(gridExtra)
pdf("reftable.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)
grid.table(reftable)
dev.off()
```

[image]

There was a simple way using `ggtexttable`

```
ggtexttable(reftable)
```

Comment: That doesn’t prevent the numbers from being turned into “##”. Do you know how I can just convert my code into a ggplot table?

Comment: @Macromind101 It worked for me but I'll find an reply again.

Comment: @Macromind101 I add new way above.

Comment: The ggtexttable() function worked, thank you! Do you know how to make the table smaller, though?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use flextable to output tables/dataframes to pdf output from rmarkdown:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
reftable <- data.frame(
Show = c("How I Met Your Mother", "There Are No Ifs, Ands, Or Buts in the Land of Fantasies and Dreams", "Leo and Carrie Simply Cannot Get Along", "Parry Needs A Dentist"), 
Score = c("181198", "234321", "306789", "16000234")
)

reftable %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  border_inner()
```

border_inner() gives all inside border lines. You can control borders with different options: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/border_inner_h.html and control size